# Filling remaining div-height

Tags: html, css

I have a **simple** for some but I can't solve the problem for some time now.

I have the problem pasted [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nanojava/7wdGw/1/) on JSFiddle.

I wanted to make `div[id='content']` to fill-in the remaining height. I've followed some tutorials on CSS about `display: table` and `display:table-row` yet, I can't have it work on mine.

Thanks in advance you would help me big-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add:

```
html{
    height:100%;
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/7wdGw/2/)

This gives your `viewport` a size from which the 100% assigned to the body can be calculated, otherwise it is effectively 100% of *nothing*. You may also want to add a `%` to the height value for `body`

Comment: I'll be accepting this since you're the first to answer it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
html, body, html > body, html body {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

The many expressions are for all browsers, IE etc is kinda buggy with only html { height: 100%; }

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7wdGw/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this css using position fixed

```
body {

    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}
#nav {

    height: 25px;
    background: blue;
}
#content {

    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 25px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS min-height property.. I normally set this using java scripts screen.height - header height - footer height..

Regards

Adam